# Docker multicontainer setup with nginx. Nginx does not recognize host (host not found in upstream)

Tags: docker, nginx

So I'm learning Docker and how to containerize apps into services. Not sure if I get it all the way.

I have three services:

1. `web-server` nginx server that binds ports 80 and 443 to outside. Basically the "frontend" of the app.
2. `app1` NodeJS app that serves content on port 3000
3. `app2` NodeJS app that serves content on port 3000, basically it's a clone of `app1` and I use it just for learning purposes.

Now my idea of running this "app" in prod would be to launch `docker-compose up` which launches all the services. Is this a correct way to launch multi container apps?

My repo structure is this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── app1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
├── app2
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
├── docker-compose.yml
├── index.html
└── web-server.conf
```

The root `Dockerfile` is for `web-server` service. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-server:
    container_name: web-server
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - app1
      - app2
  app1:
    container_name: app1
    build: ./app1
    restart: always
  app2:
    container_name: app2
    build: ./app2
    restart: always
```

The command `docker-compose up` builds `app1` and `app2` images, however it fails on `web-server` image because `nginx` throws an error:

```
host not found in upstream "app1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:11
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:11
```

`web-server` service `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:alpine
EXPOSE 80

COPY ./web-server.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./index.html /var/www/html/

RUN apk add bash

RUN nginx
```

Contents of `web-server.conf`:

```
server {
 listen *:80;
 server_name web_server;
 root /var/www/html;

 location / {
   index index.html;
 }

 location /app1 {
   proxy_pass http://app1:3000;
   proxy_redirect off;
 }

 location /app2 {
   proxy_pass http://app2:3000;
   proxy_redirect off;
 }
}
```

To me it looks like the config for nginx won't recognize `http://app1` hostname at the build time. I tried experimenting and I replaced the values for `proxy_pass` directives with `localhost`. This will build the image which I can run along with other images. If I do `bundle exec -it web-server-image /bin/bash` and I try `curl http://app1:3000` then it works. If I edit the `nginx` config to point to these URLs it starts to work.

So I think I'm getting there but it seems it won't recognize the host names when running `docker-compose up`.

Any ideas? Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just delete the two `RUN` lines at the end of the web-server `Dockerfile` this will work fine.

If you look at the [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) image's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/0f2f33169297d7571d733f3a9122e3486704c859/mainline/buster/Dockerfile) that ends with

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

which will be inherited by your image; you don't need to do anything special to cause nginx to start when the container launches.

Meanwhile, at the point the Dockerfile runs, the build sequence runs in a fairly isolated environment: none of the Compose network environment is set up, other containers aren't necessarily running, volumes aren't attached, *etc.*  The only custom settings that take effect are things specifically in the [`build:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) block in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

So: when the Dockerfile runs `RUN nginx`, it tries to start nginx inside the build environment, but that's not attached to the Compose network, so it fails.  But you don't need to do that at all because the base image already has a `CMD nginx ...` setting, and just deleting that line will fix it.

Comment: For real! Damn serves me well, I should read more about hosted docker images next time (or just build my own).

Works great now, thanks a ton. I wasted several hours on this.